# How do I share a child foreign table amongst to parent tables in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I currently have this setup:

```
class Address (models.Model):
    Member = models.ForeignKey(Member, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Address1 = models.TextField(max_length=512)
    Address2 = models.TextField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    City = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    State = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    Zip = models.TextField(max_length=25)
    Latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    Longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    Primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Phone (models.Model):
    Member = models.ForeignKey(Member, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Phone = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Member (models.Model):
    FederationID = models.FloatField(unique=True)
    UserId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    eye = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    hair = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField()


class Unit (models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Hull = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I'm trying to use a single address table to mimic both Members and Units' Address.
I'm asking if this is the right way to go about this?  Is there a more DRY version of doing this correctly.  Notice the Phone model as well.  Same question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What if multiple members share the same address? What if there are new models which also require an address? It might be a touch cleaner to put an Address field in the Member and Unit models instead of the other way around.

```
class Member(Model):
    Address = ForeignKey(...)

class Unit(Model):
    Address = ForeignKey(...)
```

and remove the member and unit fields from Address. It's more intuitive to think of a member having an address rather than an address as having a member.